# Installed libwnck-3-dev but still getting error about mising libwnck.h

Tags: linux, cmake, vala, wnck

Have installed libwnck-3-dev but when trying to compile getting:

`fatal error: libwnck/libwnck.h: No such file or directory`.

Here is [CmakeList.txt](https://pastebin.com/6uun4Prn).

File exists under this path `/usr/include/libwnck-3.0/libwnck/libwnck.h`

Comment: I need to know more information. Compilers typically have somthing called in include path, where they look for libraries. Is `libwnck/libwnck.h` on that path? What OS? What compiler (including version)? Where is the file installed? What is the compiler's include path? also please paste the snippet of code containing the `#include` directive you're using. Try `man gcc`

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had to add `${WNCK_CFLAGS}` to `add_definitions()` and `${WNCK_LIBRARIES}` to `link_libraries()`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your profile, it appears you're better at javascript, so if you don't mind I'll try to tell you how this works.

You include code in C and C++ using `#include <path/to/header.h>` or `#include "path/to/header.h"`. The former looks in the standard compiler include path for that file (e.g., `/usr/include/path/to/header.h`). The latter looks in a path relative to the source file that is being compiled.

CMake handles making sure that header file paths resolve by putting the needed paths into the compiler include path.

[It looks like libwnck uses packageconfig](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libwnck-3-dev/filelist) (which is unfortunate), installing a PC file here --> `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libwnck-3.0.pc`.

Doing a little googling, [it looks like you can use package config modules from cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html):

> `pkg_search_module(<PREFIX> [REQUIRED] [QUIET] <MODULE> [<MODULE>]*)` 
>   checks for given modules and uses the first working one

So maybe something like this:

`pkg_search_module(REQUIRED libwnck)`

Or:

`pkg_search_module(REQUIRED libwnck-3.0)`

Informationally, what you'll *usually* want to do is look at [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), but there doesn't appear to be a cmake package file installed by that debian package.